# How do I use Vim with Rebar

Tags: vim, erlang, rebar, eunit, erlang-shell

Trying to get up and running Vim + Rebar.

Separately they work but not together. What I want to achieve is to run eunit without leaving the Vim.

I guess this is doable with following plugin https://github.com/mbbx6spp/vim-rebar . Unfortunately is very poorly documented.

How do I run my tests quickly, see the output, code and once again.

All your feedback will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to integrate rebar into vim, but perhaps you could try [tmux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux)? This works for me. In one window I keep opened vim, another window i use as compilation/attach session to erlang node.

Comment: I use a similar approach with xmonad.

Answer (score 0):

One quick way to get out of Vim is to suspend it with `Ctrl+z`, run your commands, and then foreground it again with `fg` afterwards.  Works at least on bash in Os X and Ubuntu Linux.

You can also run command line commands with `:! <command name>` directly from Vim, e.g. `:! ls`.

Yet another way is to use [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), with one window running vim and another still on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found is to use a Makefile in my project. Since vim is capable of running shell commands, you can call make & have it use your makefile. Then map these shell commands to shortcuts of your choosing.

For example, my Makefile has the following:

```
test:
    $(REBAR) skip_deps=true eunit
```

In my .vimrc:

```
command MakeErlangTest !make test
nmap <leader>r :MakeErlangTest<CR>
```